# vue.js 2 mixin function called from another component, gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined"

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

I have a `search.mixin.js` file with a `search()` and I have a component `vue-productPage` in which I am calling that mixin.

when I search for a product, I am getting this error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined"**

This is my mixin:

```
const searchMixin = {
 methods: {
  search() { /** some code */}
 }
}

export default searchMixin;
```

this is my component:

```
import searchMixin from './searchMixin';

export default {
 name: 'product-page',
 mixins: [searchMixin],
 mounted() {
  this.searchMixin.search();
 }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have the `searchMiin` typo also in your real code? `this.searchMiin.search();` is missing an *x* `this.searchMixin.search()`. Also your `mixins: [searchMixin]` should be camelCased as it is in your import.

Comment: sorry for the typos. No, I do not have them in my real code. I will correct it now.

Comment: @TommyF corrected the typos. please give it another look.

Answer (score 1):

aah. got it. I was using it incorrectly. the correct way to call it will be

```
1. import it.
2. include it in mixins:[] array
3. use it `this.search()`
```

Answer (score -1):

searchMixin.js

```
export default {
  search() { /** some code */}
}
```

component

```
import searchMixin from './searchMixin.js';

export default {
 mounted() {
  searchMixin.search();
 }
}
```